# c# dictionary using textbox to select index from datagridview

Tags: c#, dictionary, indexing, datagridview, textbox

how to do indexing?
I enter a number in the textbox and retrieve the data, not the index
currently only reads the index

my code :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

        {

            int columnindex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
            {

                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Frozen.ToString();

            }
            var diction = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text.ToString());
            Dictionary<int, string> Parameters = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            {

            Parameters.Add(1, "0");
            Parameters.Add(2, "0,5");
            Parameters.Add(3, "1");

            }
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[cellindex].Cells[diction].Value.ToString();

        }
```

error: `System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text.ToString())` Check what value is in `textBox2` and be sure it's an int

Comment: integers are OK, probably numbers who are decimal... for example number 0,5